# child_process not returning correct exit code from batch file

Tags: node.js, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm trying to get the correct exit code from a batchfile using nodejs on Windows.

When run from the command line I see the expected error code:

```
ml.bat profile bootstrap
```

> ERROR: [".../deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:362:in `block in request'", ".../deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:352:in`loop'", ".../deploy/lib/RoxyHttp.rb:352:in `request'", ".../deploy/lib/MLClient.rb:110:in`go'", ".../deploy/lib/server_config.rb:1963:in `get_sid'", ".../deploy/lib/server_config.rb:2056:in`execute_query_7'",".../deploy/lib/server_config.rb:510:in `execute_query'",".../deploy/lib/server_config.rb:709:in`bootstrap'", "deploy/lib/ml.rb:168:in `'"

I verify that there exit code was non-zero:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

> 12

Below is the correspoinding code I use in NodeJS - which always gives an exit code of 0:

```
var stdout = "";
let proc = child_process.spawn("ml.bat", ["profile", "bootstrap"], {shell:true}); 

proc.stdout.on('data', d => stdout += d.toString() + '\n';);
proc.on('close', exitcode => {
    console.log(stdout);

    if (exitcode !== 0) {
        console.log('ERROR in command');
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

I have tried using several variations (exec, execSync, spawnSync) and options (shell, "cmd.exe /c") but I can never get a non-zero code using node. The program does not print any output on stderr.

Any idea how to get back the right error code in NodeJS?

Comment: You've named the parameter passed to your callback `exitcode`, but you test for `code`. I assume this is a typo in your example code, as that would result in a `ReferenceError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I added the following last line to ml.bat:

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Now it behaves identically on both windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Node to return the child process error code, you need to pass it to the exit function....

process.exit(exitcode);

As Tom mentions in his comment, "code" is undefined, so that needs to be fixed.

See [Node Docs: process_process_exitcode](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exitcode)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not actually interested in node's own exit code. Just the exit code of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use child_process.spawnSync which is a blocking call and returns ONLY after the process is complete. In addition, the object returned includes an error **property** that contains the code.

But in all cases - spawn or spawnSync, etc, I believe the result object always includes an error object if the sub-process fails for any reason. So checking for the existence of this object is probably enough.

Comment: Thanks, David. Have tried spawnSync, execSync and exec. The issue is that the code returned to NodeJS is always 0 even though windows (cmd) reports the correct errorlevel after running the batch file. Somehow the true error code is being overruled.